# Gazebo simulation stopping after some time while using reinforced learning

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, I encounter a problem while using the [gym-gazebo package](https://github.com/erlerobot/gym-gazebo). After running the example simulations the simulation ...pauses? The issue is like the ones described in [issue 49](https://github.com/erlerobot/gym-gazebo/issues/49) and [issue 47](https://github.com/erlerobot/gym-gazebo/issues/47), but the fix provided in issue 47 (reinstalling from source) still didn't work for me. Is there another way to fix this? Is the contact sensor to blame for this? This is quite problematic, because in my own simulation (gripper pick and place scenario) I would like to detect contact with the floor. Is there another way to detect collisions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18054/gazebo-simulation-stopping-after-some-time-while-using-reinforced-learning/) by [Fiddle](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3737/fiddle/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 35 on 2017-12-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The pull request mentioned on that issue has been released on Gazebo 7.1.0 on April 2016, just setup your computer to accept deb packages from OSRF as described on [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=install&tut=install_ubuntu&ver=7.0#Alternativeinstallation:step-by-step) tutorial and you should get the latest Gazebo 7 version (currently 7.9). No source install needed ;)

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1